# @Transactional annotated class can not be autowired

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm trying to perform an integration test and my class with @Transactional annotation can't be autowired into a test class with NoSuchBeanDefinitionException. I commented it out and checked a list of loaded beans and my service is there, just not injected.

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.icsynergy.scim.service.DBIntegrationServiceTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.icsynergy.scim.service.DBIntegrationService com.icsynergy.scim.service.DBIntegrationServiceTest._service; nested exception is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.icsynergy.scim.service.DBIntegrationService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

If I delete this annotation, it's injected but there is no transaction support.

Here is my class

```
@Slf4j
@Service(value = 'integrationService')
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DBIntegrationConfig.class)
//@Transactional
class DBIntegrationService implements IntegrationService, HealthIndicator {...
```

I try to inject it as

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
class DBIntegrationServiceTest {

@Autowired
DBIntegrationService _service
...
```

and below is Application.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = [
    "com.icsynergy.scim.repository",
    'com.icsynergy.scim.service',
    "com.icsynergy.scim.web",
    "com.icsynergy.scim.config"
], excludeFilters = [
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value =   OktaSCIMService.class),
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = DBIntegrationService.class)
])
@ImportResource("config.xml")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Application { 
....
```

and this is a fragment from config.xml

```
<bean name="integrationService" class="com.icsynergy.scim.service.DBIntegrationService"/>

<bean name="service" class="com.icsynergy.scim.service.OktaSCIMService">
    <property name="service" ref="integrationService"></property>
    <property name="implementedUserManagementCapabilities">
        <list value-type="com.okta.scim.server.capabilities.UserManagementCapabilities">
            <value>GROUP_PUSH</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**EDIT**: Found a workaround. As my service implements IntegrationService, so an injection of it actually helps to avoid an exception. Still don't understand what is wrong with my original injection

Will appreciate any ideas, TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would better to use interface but no the concrete class, so you should make your code like this:

```
@Autowired
IntegrationService _service
```

If you do not have the interface, you should create one.